# displaying TTS available languages in spinner

Tags: java, android, spinner, locale, text-to-speech

I started android programming recently and I'm trying to see which languages of text to speech are available on the device and display them in a spinner, but I'm running into a really weird issue.

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
package com.example.dshawn.ttsapp;

import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements

        AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    private TextToSpeech mTTS;
    Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
    List<Locale> localeList = new ArrayList<Locale>();
    List<String> country=  new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> asdf=  new ArrayList<String>();


    int sum=0;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int i) {
                if (i==TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
                    for (Locale locale : locales) {
                        int res = mTTS.isLanguageAvailable(locale);
                        if (res == TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE) {
                            sum++;
                            localeList.add(locale);
                            country.add(locale.getDisplayName());
                        }
                    }
                    asdf.add(Integer.toString(sum));


                }

            }
        });
        //Getting the instance of Spinner and applying OnItemSelectedListener on it

        Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        //Creating the ArrayAdapter instance having the country list
        ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new  ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,country);
        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        //Setting the ArrayAdapter data on the Spinner
        spin.setAdapter(aa);

    }

    //Performing action onItemSelected and onNothing selected
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),country.get(position) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

After this TTS initialization, I try and print sum, it shows 0. I try to access elements in localeList and country by doing something like String=country.get(1); and it'll give an error in the compiler saying the index I'm trying to access doesn't exist and there are 0 elements in the list. So at this point it seems like there are probably no available languages on the device, but the strange thing is when I put the country ArrayList into my spinner dropdown menu through an ArrayAdapter, the actual available countries on my device does shows up in the spinner menu, but its broken, here is a gif of what I mean:

[image]

The spinner never goes into my onItemSelected listener and the item doesn't show up in the spinner after clicking it. I went into the device's settings and those that showed up are indeed the available locales for TTS on that device. and when I remove the "if (res == TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE)" part of the code that is seemingly never accessed anyways, there will be nothing in the spinner drop-down menu. So its clearly somehow grabbing the available locales but when I tried to access the arraylist it acted like it was empty, but somehow it uses that "empty" arraylist and gets the correct countries into the spinner box but the spinner box is broken presumably because the ArrayList is broken, because I have tried the same thing with an arraylist I populate manually and the elements show up normally and I can select it normally.

What could be the issue here? I have tried everything I could think of, all I know is the problem lies in the TTS initialization portion.

Basically I can't access any of the items that were set or added in the "onInit" method for the TTS, which also causes my spinner to break.

Comment: I can give a code sample that does what you're trying to do, but if you want to know why your approach isn't working, you'll need to post the whole activity.

Comment: I have added the full code, I don't know if it will be much help though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem was that you were creating the adapter (using the country list) before the list had been populated (because the TTS was not initialized yet).

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private TextToSpeech mTTS;
    Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
    List<Locale> localeList = new ArrayList<Locale>();
    List<String> country = new ArrayList<String>();

    // * - Move these two variables out here
    ArrayAdapter<String> aa;
    Spinner spin;

    int sum = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Log.i("XXX", "onCreate() was called");
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
            @Override
            public void onInit(int i) {
                if (i == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                    // * - delay important tasks until TTS is initialized
                    startWhenTTSIsInitialized();
                }
            }
        });

        //Getting the instance of Spinner and applying OnItemSelectedListener on it
        spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    }

    private void startWhenTTSIsInitialized() {

        Log.i("XXX", "startWhenTTSIsInitialized() was called");
        for (Locale locale : locales) {
            int res = mTTS.isLanguageAvailable(locale);
            if (res == TextToSpeech.LANG_COUNTRY_AVAILABLE) {
                sum++;
                localeList.add(locale);
                // * - 'country' is used to populate the adapter, so
                // this line must come first
                country.add(locale.getDisplayName());
            }
        }

        //Creating the ArrayAdapter instance having the country list
        // * - now it's safe to set the adapter because the country list has been populated
        aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, country);
        aa.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        //Setting the ArrayAdapter data on the Spinner
        spin.setAdapter(aa);
        spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    }

    //Performing action onItemSelected and onNothing selected
    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long id) {

        Log.i("XXX", "onItemSelected() was called");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), country.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where are you calling `String=country.get(1);`?  Because this is a callback you won't know when it will be called.  If you place the code inside the `onInit` after the `if` statement block do you see the value?

Comment: It seems like I can access the values in onInit, I tried to display sum again and it shows 7 when accessed from inside of the onInit method. But I can't move my spinner into onInit because my ArrayAdapter can't be applied inside of the onInit method. is there a way to preserve the values after onInit?

Comment: Yea this would be a great time to use Rx by creating a stream and placing the values on the stream when onInit finishes then subscribing in onResume (don't forget to dispose in onPause or use Autodispose by Uber).  Another option is to have a listener class and call the listener which updates the spinner (the listener could be implemented by the activity or you could architect it to be more testable with a pure java class)